# Second eigenvalue Fokker Planck equation physical meaning

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The problem of the escape over a barrier can be modeled by the Fokker-Planck equation.

When solving the F-P equation using eigenfunctions and eigenvalues expansion, many authors state the relation between the lowest eigenvalues and the Mean First Passage Time.

Are there any physical quantities related with the second, third and so on eigenvalues?